# Getting cors error when bearer token is passed to API from angular to spring boot backend

Tags: angular, spring-boot, cors, spring-security-oauth2

I have tried with all code but same cors issue. Help me for this.

Here are the configuration for the backend spring boot

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.jwt.crypto.sign.RsaVerifier;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.configurers.ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JwtAccessTokenConverter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JwtTokenStore;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter;

@Configuration
public class OAuthConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {


    @Value("${spring.oauth.clientId}")
    private String clientId;

    @Value("${spring.oauth.clientSecret}")
    private String clientSecret;

    @Value("${spring.oauth.accessTokenValidity}")
    private int accessTokenValidity;

    @Value("${spring.oauth.refreshTokenValidity}")
    private int refreshTokenValidity;

    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;


    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public OAuthConfiguration(BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder, AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security.allowFormAuthenticationForClients();
        security.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.applyPermitDefaultValues();

        // add allow-origin to the headers
        config.addAllowedHeader("access-control-allow-origin");

        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/oauth/token", config);
        CorsFilter filter = new CorsFilter(source);
        security.addTokenEndpointAuthenticationFilter(filter);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient(clientId).secret(passwordEncoder.encode(clientSecret))
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token")
                .scopes("read","write")
                .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT", "USER","ADMIN")
                .autoApprove(true)
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(accessTokenValidity)
                .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(refreshTokenValidity);
    }


@Override
public void configure(final AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
    endpoints
            .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter())
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
}

    @Bean
    JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        return converter;
    }
}
```

**Security Config Class**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter;

import java.util.Arrays;

//@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig  extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(@Qualifier("userService")UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        /***
         * Note down to uncomment
         */
//        http.csrf().disable().cors().and()
//                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
//                //.and()
//                //.cors()
//                .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/oauth/token")
//                .permitAll()
//                .antMatchers("/parking/**").permitAll()
//                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll()
//                .anyRequest().authenticated();
//        http
//                .csrf().disable()
//                .anonymous().disable()
//                .authorizeRequests()
//                .antMatchers("/api-docs/**").permitAll();

        http.csrf().disable().cors().and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/parking/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/oauth/token").permitAll().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

//    private Customizer<CorsConfigurer<HttpSecurity>> corsConfigurationCustomizer(){
//        return new Customizer<CorsConfigurer<HttpSecurity>>() {
//            @Override
//            public void customize(CorsConfigurer<HttpSecurity> httpSecurityCorsConfigurer) {
//                httpSecurityCorsConfigurer.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource());
//            }
//        };
//    }

//    @Override
//    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
//        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/**");
//    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setPasswordEncoder( bCryptPasswordEncoder() );
        provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        return provider;
    }
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://127.0.0.1:4200"));
        configuration.addAllowedHeader("*");
        configuration.addAllowedMethod("*");
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
//@Bean
//public CorsFilter corsFilter(){
//    CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
//    corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(false);
//    corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
//    corsConfiguration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Origin","Access-Control-Allow-Origin","Content-Type",
//            "Accept", "Authorization", "Origin, Accept", "X-Requested-With",
//            "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers"));
//    corsConfiguration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Origin", "Content-Type", "Accept","Authorization",
//            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"));
//    corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST","PUT","DELETE","OPTIONS"));
//    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
//    urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfiguration);
//    return new CorsFilter(urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource);
//}
//    @Bean
//    public FilterRegistrationBean<CORSFilter> filterRegistrationBean(){
//        FilterRegistrationBean<CORSFilter> registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>(new CORSFilter());
//        registrationBean.setName("CORS FIlter");
//        registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/*");
//        registrationBean.setOrder(1);
//        return registrationBean;
//    }
}
```

Tried with WebConfiguration also

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
//@EnableWebSecurity
//@Configuration
//public class WebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
//
//    @Override
//    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
//        registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("http://127.0.0.1:4200").allowedMethods("*")
//                .allowCredentials(true);
//    }
//}
```

Tried With Creating Cors Filter class

```
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

//public class CORSFilter extends GenericFilterBean implements Filter {
//    @Override
//    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
//            throws IOException, ServletException {
//
//        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
//        httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
//        httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*");
//        httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
//        httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "*");
//        httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
//        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
//       }
//    }
@Order(1)
public class CORSFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {


    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-PINGOTHER,Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Authorization");
        res.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "xsrf-token");
        if ("OPTIONS".equals(req.getMethod())) {
            res.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the angular code

```
export class LoginService {
  userDto: UserDto = new UserDto();
  private baseUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/parking';
  
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  login(login:login,token:string):Observable<Object>{
    console.log('Bearer '+token);
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type','application/json')
      .set('Authorization',"Bearer "+token).set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*').set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE,OPTIONS')
      .set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token')
      .set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials','true')
    };
    this.userDto.setBatchNo(login.getBatchNo());
    this.userDto.setPassword(login.getPassword());
    return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}/getUser`,this.userDto,httpOptions);
  }
}
```

Here /oauth/token api works fine, but when I pass token to /getUser api , cors error comes

[image]

Attaching console error
[image]

Comment: Can you please copy the error from console and share here.

Comment: @RohitAgarwal this is the error. Added console error in the question ``Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/parking/getUser' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.``

Comment: In preflight request 401 status is coming. Can you please check why authentication is not working for OPTIONS method.

Comment: Also no need to set Access-Controll-Allow-* headers in angular code. Please remove them

Comment: @RohitAgarwal I have removed what you said for angular. For preflight I just used that options configuration but same error for the cors. Did you tried at your end something to get the solution

Answer (score 0):

Solved By adding code in **WebConfiguration** class

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration implements Filter,WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**");
    }



    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
        System.out.println("WebConfig; "+request.getRequestURI());
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With,observe");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Authorization");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "USERID");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "ROLE");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "responseType");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "observe");
        System.out.println("Request Method: "+request.getMethod());
        if (!(request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("OPTIONS"))) {
            try {
                filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Pre-flight");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST,GET,DELETE,PUT");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Expose-Headers"+"Authorization, content-type," +
                    "USERID"+"ROLE"+
                    "access-control-request-headers,access-control-request-method,accept,origin,authorization,x-requested-with,responseType,observe");
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        }
    }
}
```